# how to display script output to web page flask / django

Tags: python, flask

hi i create server client model in which client keep checking if new device add or not and send response to server side its working fine what i want to display the response i get from client to server on web browser continuously using flask or Django.

this is my client code

```
from socket import *
import subprocess, string, time

host = 'localhost'  # '127.0.0.1' can also be used
port = 53000
sock = socket()

# Connecting to socket
sock.connect((host, port))  # Connect takes tuple of host and port

def detect_device(previous):
    import socket
    username2 = socket.gethostname()
    ip=socket.gethostbyname(username2)
    total = subprocess.run('lsblk | grep disk | wc -l', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
    time.sleep(3)

# if conditon if new device add
    if total>previous:
     response = "Device Added in " + username2 + " " + ip
     sock.send(response.encode())
# if no new device add or remove
    elif total==previous:
     detect_device(previous)
# if device remove
    else:
     response = "Device Removed in " + username2 + " " + ip

     sock.send(response.encode())
# Infinite loop to keep client running.


while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    if (data == b'Hi'):
        while True:
            detect_device(subprocess.run(' lsblk | grep disk | wc -l', shell=True , stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout)

sock.close()
```

this is my server side code

```
from socket import *
# Importing all from thread
import threading

# Defining server address and port
host = 'localhost'
port = 53000

# Creating socket object
sock = socket()
# Binding socket to a address. bind() takes tuple of host and port.
sock.bind((host, port))
# Listening at the address
sock.listen(5)  # 5 denotes the number of clients can queue

def clientthread(conn):
    # infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
    while True:
        # Sending message to connected client
        conn.send('Hi'.encode())  # send only takes string
        data =conn.recv(1024)
        print (data.decode())
while True:
    # Accepting incoming connections
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    # Creating new thread. Calling clientthread function for this function and passing conn as argument.
    thread = threading.Thread(target=clientthread, args=(conn,))
    thread.start()

conn.close()
sock.close()
```

this is output on server side

`Device Added in wraith 192.168.10.9`

`Device Removed in wraith 192.168.10.9`

i need to display this output on web page .

Answer (score 0):

Flask and Django are Web application frameworks that are designed for the HTTP protocol, but you're using the low-level `socket` library and basically not using any established protocol. If you want to use Flask/Django because you want to have a broadcasting platform for the results of your device-watching client-side script, then I recommend that instead of `socket`, use `requests` [(link)](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) in your client script to send an HTTP POST request to your Flask/Django Web app. As for how to build the app, well there are tutorials for that. I do want to note that the minimalist Flask is probably a better fit for this project than the more opinionated Django framework.

Comment: hi, can you change the client code how i post the request thank you.

Comment: @niftykhan The [`requests` documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) shows how to do HTTP requests, POST method included, with that library. As for the exact code you'll need, it will depend on the request structure that your web application will expect (a.k.a. the API that you will build between the client and server, though it doesn't need to be complicated).